# jQuery responsive hover and click swtich

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to switch `hover` and `click` when window size change

```
function checkWidth() {
var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize > 480) {
        $('#clickPoint').on('click', function(){
        ......//code
        });
    }else {
        $('#clickPoint').on('hover',function(){
        ......//code        
        });
    }
}();

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

However I found hover is always on, so I had to change to this way

```
var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize > 480) {
            $('#clickPoint').on('click', function(){
            ......//code
            });
        }else {
           $('#clickPoint').off('click', function(){
            ......//code
            });
            $('#clickPoint').on('hover',function(){
            ......//code        
            });
        }
    }();
```

but still doesn't work properly, if someone has a better solution?Thanks

Comment: Can you explain "still doesn't work properly"?

Comment: Please produce a working example showing your issue by adding your html code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at `$window.width()`. I suspect that. Try changing it to `$(window).width()`. Make changes to the code that you provided at the top. Because the code at the bottom looks messed up.

Also make sure to check the window width by using an alert or log. Just to make sure that the if statement is working right.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
        var permit=2;
        $('#clickPoint').on('click', function(){
            if(permit==0)
            {
        ......//code
            }
        });
             $('#clickPoint').on('hover',function(){
            if(permit==1)
            {
        ......//code        
            }
        });
function checkWidth() {
var windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize > 480) {
        permit=0;

    }else {
       permit=1;
    }
}

$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```